# Laravel: call global function for only authenticated users

Tags: php, laravel

I want to call a global function for only authenticated users to check if their account has been verified. **From all routes**

Function.

```
public function verifyAccount()
{
   if (Auth::user()->verified == 0)
   {
      return redirect('/checkpoint');
   }
   return redirect('/home');
}
```

And that function is currently enabled in the base route.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   if (Auth::check()) {
      UserService::verifyAccount();
   }
   return redirect('/home');
});
```

My problem is currently this only works for the home/base route. I was hoping there would be an easier way to implement for ALL routes without having to manually copy and paste to each route.

I would love to use the route group feature `['middleware' => 'auth']` to my routes. but i cant because the website allows for both guest and authenticated users.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @tomloprod is a more suitable answer for what you're trying to achieve. I'd go with his answer.

Comment: Thanks will give this a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `middleware` inside `app/Http/Middleware` directory:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class VerifyAccount{

       public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

            if ($request->user()->verified) {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
                //////////// return redirect()->route('checkpoint');
            }

       }
}
```

Register your new `middleware` inside `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    ...
    'verifyAccount' => VerifyAccount::class
];
```

And using it in your `routes.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['verifyAccount']], function () {
    //////////// Here all your routes

    ////// Example:
    Route::get('myProtectedRoute', array('uses' => 'MyController@MyControllerFunction'))->name('myActionName'); 
});
```

Isn't Laravel amazing? :-)

Comment: You can make any changes you want at the `VerifyAccount` `handle` function to suit your needs.

Comment: Holy crap! it worked. i only had to adjust the middleware to check if a user is logged in or not.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a middleware for this function.. and create route group for check all routes. 
for example

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['verifyAccount'] function ()
{
    Route::get('dashboard', 'admin\AdminController@dashboard')->name('adminDashboard');
}
```